# How to skip validations while creating a object in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a existing app. One model has number of fields and they have set validations for many of them. I am trying create a object for testing purpose. I only need couple of fields. How do I skip the validation method and create an object?

```
class Article 
   validate :article_validation
   #...rest of the model

end
```

All I want to do is do

`Article.create(title: "sfsfsd")` in console.

And skip rest of the fields

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
a = Article.new(title: "sfsfsd")
a.save(validate: false)
```

> Note that save also has the ability to skip validations if passed
>   validate: false as an argument. This technique should be used with
>   caution.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations